Wrong calculus in Boxplot
I want to draw a boxplot using the PGFplots as in the following MWE:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% Nice color sets, see see http://colorbrewer2.org/ 
%\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
% initialize Set1-4 from colorbrewer (we're comparing 4 classes),
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.13} 
% Tikz is loaded automatically by pgfplots
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics, pgfplots.colorbrewer} 
% provides \pgfplotstabletranspose
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[y=1cm,enlarge y limits=2]
    \addplot+ [,boxplot,blue]
        table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            24\\24\\25\\25\\27\\30\\32\\32\\35\\43\\
    }
    [above]
node at
  (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{lower whisker},1)
  {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{lower whisker}}}
node at
  (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{lower quartile},1)
  {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{lower quartile}}}
node[left] at
  (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{median},0.5)
  {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{median}}}
node at
  (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{upper quartile},1)
  {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{upper quartile}}}
node at
  (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{upper whisker},1)
  {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{upper whisker}}}
;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

whose output is:

compiled with LuaTex. However, the median (correct value is 28.5 not 27) and the other bounds are wrongs. How can I fix this?

Note that there are multiple definitions of quantiles (and therefore also of the median), see Hyndman & Fan (1996). The quantile function for R implements the nine version this paper recommends.

Just a suggestion. To make statistics, use the R statistical language.
MWE.Rnw (or MWE.Rtex in Overleaf):
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
<<echo=F,dev="tikz",fig.height=3, fig.width=5>>=
x<- c(24,24,25,25,27,30,32,32,35,43)
boxplot(x,horizontal=TRUE,border="blue", col="cyan", lw=2,lty=1, range = 0)
text(x=fivenum(x), labels =fivenum(x), y=1.3)
@
\end{document}

Alternatively, if you want it with outliers:
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
<<echo=F,dev="tikz",fig.height=3, fig.width=5>>=
x<- c(24,24,25,25,27,30,32,32,35,43)
res <- boxplot(x,horizontal=TRUE,border="blue", col="cyan",lw=2,lty=1)
text(x=res$stat, labels =res$stat, y=1.3)
@
\end{document}




From the pgfplots manual, the p-quartile is defined as

With your data
24 24 25 25 27 30 32 32 35 43

N=10. So

the median (p=0.5) is the N*0.5 = 5th value: 27;
the lower quartile (p=0.25) is the average of the 2nd (24) and 3rd (25) values: 24.5;
the upper quartile (p=0.75) is the average of the 7th (32) and 8th (32) values: 32.

It's seems to me that all calculations are correct.
EDIT
It's not my field of expertise, but I guess there are many definitions of statistical quantities. You can maybe play with /pgfplots/boxplot/estimator. For example
\pgfplotsset{
  /pgfplots/boxplot/estimator=R7
}

gives

Choose in the pgfplots manual the setting corresponding to your need.
Full code:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.13}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics, pgfplots.colorbrewer}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{
  /pgfplots/boxplot/estimator=R7
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[y=1cm,enlarge y limits=2]
    \addplot+ [,boxplot,blue]
        table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            24\\24\\25\\25\\27\\30\\32\\32\\35\\43\\
    }
    [above]
node[below] at
  (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{lower whisker},0)
  {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{lower whisker}}}
node at
  (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{lower quartile},1)
  {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{lower quartile}}}
node[left] at
  (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{median},0.5)
  {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{median}}}
node at
  (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{upper quartile},1)
  {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{upper quartile}}}
node[below] at
  (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{upper whisker},0)
  {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{upper whisker}}}
;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Maybe the calculus is correct, but the result is wrong. The median is not 27.

@Fran In fact, I don't know. I edited the answer, pgfplots provides many statistical estimators. This is set with /pgfplots/boxplot/estimator.

Good Edit. In its simplest form pgfplots just draws the shape, once the user provided all relevant data, like the correct median. The long Rx list seems impressive, but lacks explanation. I.e. I‘m not aware, that R1, R2 etc. are some kind of standard, everybody knows by heart, like e.g. the harmonic oscillator recalls clear and long stories for physicists, engineers and similar. Moreover, certain statistical calculations can’t do without higher functions found in Abramowitz’ Handbook … where Tikz certainly reaches a limit.

I have not idea what the hell could mean sentences as "the estimator type 7 used by R", but citing textually the same pgfplots manual, the median is simply when  "half of the points are less and half of the points are larger", that is, either just the middle point (odd points) or the mean of the two middle values (even points).  Afaik, big end point.

The mystery of the types was solved by Stephan Kolassa, but IMHO different quantile calculation methods can lead to Q2 values that can differ significantly in small datasets, but this does not make the median a relative value, i.e., the way the Q2 is calculated affects whether it aligns perfectly with the median, but the median is only one.  For the record, the default in R is the type 7  (=28.5 in this case)  that matches with the standard median() function, as well as all the other types except the 1, 3 and 4, that produce the less "accurate" result (=27)  in this case.
